# How do I add img from my database (mongodb) to a bootstarp carousel using for Each

Tags: node.js

I tried using forEach to loop through my database, and display images in a bootstrap carousel, but only the first image in the database is displaying along with other details pertaining  to the img is showing, the rest of the images isn't and the carousel buttons aint working as well

below is my ejs code

```
<h5>Toyota Cars</h5>

  <div id="car-slide" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
     <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#car-slide" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#car-slide" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#car-slide" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <% toyotas.forEach((toyota, inx)=>{ %> 
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    
        <% if (inx ==0){ %> 
          <div class= "carousel-item active">
            <img src="<%= toyota.image%>" class="d-block w-100" id="car-caro"alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
                <div class="arrow">
                    <div class="mil">
                        <p><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-right-from-square" id="millage"></i></p>
                   
                        <p class=""><%=toyota.millage %> </p>
                        <h6 class="car-name">
                          <%= toyota.carName %> 
                      </h6> 
                       
                        <div class="car-properties">
                          <p><%= toyota.seater %> </p>
                          <p><%= toyota.mechnism %> </p>
                          <p><%= toyota.combustion %> </p>
                  
                        </div> 
                       
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
           <% }else { %> 
              <div class= "carousel-item">
                <img src="<%= toyota.image%>" class="d-block w-100" id="car-caro"alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <div class="arrow">
                    <div class="mil">
                        <p><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-right-from-square" id="millage"></i></p>
                   
                        <p class=""><%=toyota.millage %> </p>
                        <h6 class="car-name">
                          <%= toyota.carName %> 
                      </h6> 
                       
                        <div class="car-properties">
                          <p><%= toyota.seater %> </p>
                          <p><%= toyota.mechnism %> </p>
                          <p><%= toyota.combustion %> </p>
                  
                        </div> 
                       
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              
                </div>
           <% } %> 

    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#car-slide" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#car-slide" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <%})%>
```

Comment: Use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()` and see if it works. :)

Comment: Didn't work or perhaps, i didn't get it right

Comment: Remove pair of `{}` after the `=>` in `toyotas.map((toyota, inx) => ` and directly render the html see if it works :)

Comment: still, didn't work, and I'm not getting any error feedback

Comment: You have data in `toyotas`? please cross check that if it's an empty array.

Comment: Yeah I have data in Toyotas, it is my mongodb cluster.  Only the first img is displaying in the carousel, the rest are not displaying